# Setting progress bar visibility to View.GONE makes the whole notification invisible

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

I create a notification from my custom layout with a progress bar. When the task is finished I make the progress bar invisible, this is working fine with Android 2.3.3 and newer versions. In older version, whole notification becomes invisible, no icon, no text, no nothing, but the "Clear" button becomes activated which means there is a notification.

How I created the notification and updated using `NotificationCompat` from Android Support Library;

Following variables are declared in AsyncTask class as private members;

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private RemoteViews contentView;
private Notification n;
private int nId; //Notification ID
```

AsyncTask Functions;

When download start

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.custom_notification);
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, nTitle);
            contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.notification_progressbar, 100, 0,
                    false);
            contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            contentView.setTextViewText(
                    R.id.notification_progresstext,
                    "" + df.format(total) + " MB / "
                            + df.format((float) fileLength) + " MB");

            nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker(mp3Name);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                // sets FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
                nBuilder.setOngoing(true).setContent(contentView)
                        .setAutoCancel(false);
                n = nBuilder.build();
            } else {
                // required, otherwise will crash with an IllegalArgException
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                nBuilder.setContentIntent(pend);
                n = nBuilder.build();
                n.contentView = contentView;
                // since flags are ignored in earlier version set them directly
                n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
                        | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            }

            nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nManager.notify(nId, n);


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.download_started,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

On progress update

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        if (progress[0] != currentProgress) {
            if (progress[0] >= 100) {
                // PROGRESS 100
                nManager.cancel(nId);

                nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setTicker(mp3Name);

                contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.notification_progressbar,
                        100, progress[0], false);
                contentView.setTextViewText(
                        R.id.notification_progresstext,
                        "" + df.format(total / 1048576f) + " MB / "
                                + df.format(fileLength / 1048576f) + " MB");
                contentView.setViewVisibility(
                        R.id.notification_progressbar, View.GONE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + fullFilePath),
                        "audio/mpeg");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                nBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                    nBuilder.setOngoing(false).setContent(contentView)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
                    n = nBuilder.build();
                } else {
                    n = nBuilder.build();
                    n.contentView = contentView;
                    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                }
                nManager.notify(nId, n);
            } else {
                // PROGRESS < 100
                contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.notification_progressbar,
                        100, progress[0], false);
                contentView.setTextViewText(
                        R.id.notification_progresstext,
                        "" + df.format(total / 1048576f) + " MB / "
                                + df.format(fileLength / 1048576f) + " MB");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                    nBuilder.setContent(contentView);
                    n = nBuilder.build();
                } else {
                    n = nBuilder.build();
                    n.contentView = contentView;
                }
                nManager.notify(nId, n);
            }

            // nManager.notify(nId, n);
            currentProgress = progress[0];
        }

    }
```

I have to remove `contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.notification_progressbar, View.GONE);`, then it looks ugly.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but have you tried View.INVISIBLE?

Comment: @uval yes I tried that, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

It is just not possible with Android 2.3 or lower.

Clickable `Notification` buttons work only on Android 3 or higher.

Comment: That didn't help, same result. BTW, I can set the notification_title or notification_progresstext to View.GONE, but not the progressbar itself.

Comment: I don't understand, what does clickable Notification have to do with progressbar visibility? My problem does not exist on Android 2.3.3